# URL Rewrite all folders at root of subdomain to folder in a different file path

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I need to rewrite from `sub.domain.com/Xfolder/yfile.htm` --> `/local_path/all_customers/xfolder/yfile.htm`

There are many xfolders in the all_customers folder. No folders or files exist in the IIS root of sub.domain.com. All of the folders and files actually exist in a local folder and not a URL.

I need something like this code, but I also need to allow for URL variables.

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^file_path_to_folders\all_customers\$ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: `match` tag shows common mistake 1 in https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59. **URL** Rewrite module is designed to rewrite **URL**, so wishing it rewrites to folders not URLs won't come true.

Answer (score 0):

URL rewrite module can only rewrite a URL to another URL so it is unavailable to rewrite URL to a physical path folder directly. You can create another website with the root folder `/local_path/all_customers/`. So that you can easily reverse proxy `siteA/Xfolder/yfile.htm` to `siteB/Xfolder/yfile.htm`.

Please install ARR and reverse proxy to achieve this.
[ARR and reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing)

And reverse Proxy functionality is disabled by default, so you must begin by enabling it in Application Request Routing" feature.

Comment: Can I just create a virtual directory in the IIS site where to files exist? Can you help with the code for the solution? Thank you!!